# How to generate AA,AB,AC...,BA,BB,BC...,CA,CB,CC,...,ZZ series in R?

Tags: r, combinations

I have to generate an alphabet series (AA,AB,AC...,BA,BB,BC...,CA,CB,CC,...,ZZ) similar to the default column names of an excel file.

I tried it by using the combination function as follows,

```
combn(LETTERS,2)
```

However, this did not match with my requirement.

Comment: Try `do.call(paste0, expand.grid(rep(list(LETTERS), 2))[2:1])`  With this you can generate also for n =3 i.e `do.call(paste0, expand.grid(rep(list(LETTERS), 3))[3:1])` and above
`

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much. It is the one I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

```
as.vector(sapply(LETTERS,function(x) sapply(LETTERS , function(y) paste0(x,y))))
```

Comment: Nice answer. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) out for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be `outer`

```
out <- c(outer(LETTERS, LETTERS, paste0))
head(sort(out))
# [1] "AA" "AB" "AC" "AD" "AE" "AF"
```